# Console.Read() не отрабатывает

Tags: c#

Как я понимаю, `Read()` должен отработать при каждой итерации, но увы нет

```
public static int[] fillArray() {
    int[] tmpMarks = new int[5]; 
    for (int i = 0; i &lt tmpMarks.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Put " + i + "element");
        tmpMarks[i] = Console.Read();
    }
    return tmpMarks;
}
```

Только три почему-то.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `Read` читает один символ из входного потока, включая символы перевода карретки и новой строки.

Вместо этого метода используйте метод `ReadLine` , а затем преобразуйте считанную строку в целое число одним из методов по вашему желанию.

Например

```
for (int i = 0; i &lt tmpMarks.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Put " + i + "element: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tmpMarks[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `Console.Read` используйте [`Console.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) с последующим парсингом введенной строки в `int`.
Например, вот так:

```
public static int[] FillArray()
{
    int[] tmpMarks = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpMarks.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Put " + i + " element");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tmpMarks[i]))
            Console.WriteLine("Value cannot be parsed. Try again.");
    }
    return tmpMarks;
}
```